# scrapy parse multiple urls

Tags: python, scrapy

I am having a problem with running more than 1 URL here:

```
cmdline.execute("scrapy parse http://example.com --spider=myspider".split())
```

I am looking at the documentation here: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/commands.html#parse but from what I can see it does not look like there is a way. I also do not want to use the start_urls within the class so any solution other then that would be preferable, thanks.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9681114/how-to-give-url-to-scrapy-for-crawling.

Comment: Could you add more details? What exactly are you trying to do? Try to show us problem input and expected output.

Comment: just parse 2 urls ie. - "scrapy parse http://example.com, http://example1.com --spider=myspider"

Comment: Oh alec that works actually thanks never saw that post