# Passing list as arguments in Scrapy

Tags: python, flask, scrapy

I am trying to build an application using Flask and Scrapy. I have to pass the `list` of urls to spider. I tried using the following syntax:

```
__init__: in Spider
self.start_urls = ["http://www.google.com/patents/" + x for x in u]

Flask Method
u = ["US6249832", "US20120095946"]
os.system("rm static/s.json; scrapy crawl patents -d u=%s -o static/s.json" % u)
```

I know similar thing can be done by reading file having required urls, but can I pass list of urls for crawling?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Override spider's `__init__()` method:

```
class MySpider(Spider):
    name = 'my_spider'    

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs): 
      super(MySpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs) 

      endpoints = kwargs.get('start_urls').split(',')
      self.start_urls = ["http://www.google.com/patents/" + x for x in endpoints]
```

And pass the list of endpoints through the `-a` command line argument:

```
scrapy crawl patents -a start_urls="US6249832,US20120095946" -o static/s.json
```

See also:

- [How to give URL to scrapy for crawling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9681114/how-to-give-url-to-scrapy-for-crawling)

---

Note that you can also *run Scrapy from script*:

- [How to run Scrapy from within a Python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13437402/how-to-run-scrapy-from-within-a-python-script)
- [Scrapy Very Basic Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18838494/scrapy-very-basic-example)

Comment: This looks like a very promising solution, this doesn't even require storing patent numbers in a list. Thanks.