# Python: Problems sending 'list' of urls to scrapy spider to scrape

Tags: python, scrapy

Trying to send a 'list' of urls to scrapy to crawl via a certain spider via using a long string, then splitting the string inside the crawler. I've tried copying the format that was given in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9681114/how-to-give-url-to-scrapy-for-crawling) answer.

The list I'm trying to send to the crawler is `future_urls`

```
    >>> print future_urls
    set(['https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/q/hp?s=ALXN&a=06&b=10&c=2012&d=06&e=10&f=2015&g=m', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/hp?s=TFW.L&a=06&b=10&c=2012&d=06&e=10&f=2015&g=m', 'https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/q/hp?s=DLTR&a=06&b=10&c=2012&d=06&e=10&f=2015&g=m', 'https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/q/hp?s=AGNC&a=06&b=10&c=2012&d=06&e=10&f=2015&g=m', 'https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/q/hp?s=HMSY&a=06&b=10&c=2012&d=06&e=10&f=2015&g=m', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/hp?s=BATS.L&a=06&b=10&c=2012&d=06&e=10&f=2015&g=m'])
```

Then sending it to the crawler through:

```
command4 = ("scrapy crawl future -o future_portfolios_{0} -t csv -a future_urls={1}").format(input_file, str(','.join(list(future_urls))))

>>> print command4
scrapy crawl future -o future_portfolios_input_10062008_10062012_ver_1.csv -t csv -a future_urls=https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/q/hp?s=ALXN&a=06&b=10&c=2012&d=06&e=10&f=2015&g=m,http://finance.yahoo.com/q/hp?s=TFW.L&a=06&b=10&c=2012&d=06&e=10&f=2015&g=m,https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/q/hp?s=DLTR&a=06&b=10&c=2012&d=06&e=10&f=2015&g=m,https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/q/hp?s=AGNC&a=06&b=10&c=2012&d=06&e=10&f=2015&g=m,https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/q/hp?s=HMSY&a=06&b=10&c=2012&d=06&e=10&f=2015&g=m,http://finance.yahoo.com/q/hp?s=BATS.L&a=06&b=10&c=2012&d=06&e=10&f=2015&g=m
>>> type(command4)
<type 'str'>
```

**My crawler (partial):**

```
class FutureSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = "future"
allowed_domains = ["finance.yahoo.com", "ca.finance.yahoo.com"]
start_urls = ['https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/q/hp?s=%5EIXIC']

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(FutureSpider, self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
    self.future_urls = kwargs.get('future_urls').split(',')
    self.rate_returns_len_min = 12
    self.required_amount_of_returns = 12
    for x in self.future_urls:
            print "Going to scrape:"
            print x

def parse(self, response):

    if self.future_urls:
        for x in self.future_urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(x, self.stocks1)
```

However, what is printed out from `print 'going to scrape:', x` is:

```
Going to scrape:
https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/q/hp?s=ALXN
```

Only one url, and it's only a portion of the first url in `future_urls` which is obviously problematic.

Can't seem to figure out why the crawler won't scrape all of the urls in `future_urls`...

Comment: Can you put a breakpoint at "for x in self.future_urls:" in __init__, the if statement should work as desired on both list and set. The only explanation is that future_urls only has 1 element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's stopping when it hits the ampersand (`&`), you can escape it by using `urllib.quote`.

For example:

```
import urllib

escapedurl = urllib.quote('https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/q/hp?s=ALXN&a=06&b=10&c=2012&d=06&e=10&f=2015&g=m')
```

Then you get it back to normal you can do:

```
>>>>urllib.unquote(escapedurl)
https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/q/hp?s=ALXN&a=06&b=10&c=2012&d=06&e=10&f=2015&g=m
```

Comment: That was exactly it! Would never have guessed! Thanks!