# How to pass start_urls to scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

Based on suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9681114/how-to-give-url-to-scrapy-for-crawling), I'm trying:

```
scrapy crawl spider-name -a start_urls="https://start-url.com/"
```

I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scrapy/core/engine.py", line 129, in _next_request
    request = next(slot.start_requests)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scrapy/spiders/__init__.py", line 77, in start_requests
    yield Request(url, dont_filter=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scrapy/http/request/__init__.py", line 25, in __init__
    self._set_url(url)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scrapy/http/request/__init__.py", line 73, in _set_url
    raise ValueError(f'Missing scheme in request url: {self._url}')
```

To reproduce, run the following:

```
scrapy startproject example_project
cd example_project
scrapy genspider spider1 https://stackoverflow.com
scrapy crawl spider1 -a start_urls="https://stackoverflow.com"
```

Comment: Please share the code

Comment: I edited the question, and included a similar example

Answer (score 0):

The command `scrapy genspider` generates this code:

```
import scrapy


class Spider1Spider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'spider1'
    allowed_domains = ['https://stackoverflow.com']
    start_urls = ['https://stackoverflow.com/']

    def parse(self, response):
        pass
```

This does not handle `start_urls` as a command line parameter. To make it do so, follow the guide you linked. Something like

```
import scrapy


class Spider1Spider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'spider1'
    allowed_domains = ['https://stackoverflow.com']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Spider1Spider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.start_urls = kwargs.get('start_urls').split(',')

    def parse(self, response):
        pass
```

will work.

Note: `self.start_urls` expects a list, so if receives a string it will complain.

Comment: I assumed this can be implied without explicitly defining `self.start_urls = ...` or maybe there is some way that already exists for achieving the same result.

Comment: It isn't handled implicitly, no. See the docs for `scrapy.Spider` and `start_urls` here: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy-spider .

Specifying the urls explicitly is the only way.

Comment: Since there's no difference between this answer and the ones [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9681114/how-to-give-url-to-scrapy-for-crawling) this can possibly be considered a duplicate, so I may close the question.